# Batch convert geotiff to jpg but ensure nodata is white

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I've been using `gdal_translate` to convert geotiffs of rotated paper maps to jpg+wld, but nodata sections would always turn up black (i.e., where the original data has been rotated).

So based on other answers on the web I've tried using a combination of `gdalwarp` and `gdal_translate` as such:

```
for %i in (*.tif) do gdalwarp -srcnodata "0,0,0" -dstnodata "255,255,255" %i %i_fix.tif
for %i in (*_fix.tif) do gdal_translate -of JPEG -co "worldfile=yes" %i %~ni.jpg
```

I've tried many parameters for `-srcnodata` and `-dstnodata`, with/without the alpha band, `"0"`, `0`, but still get large black edges/spaces in the output jpg.

How can I ensure that nodata ends up white in the resultant jpg instead of black? Using only gdal, preferably. I would like to avoid python scripts for now if possible.